# Rounding float to single decimal (specific problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python but very interested in learning. For a uni Python course I am to create a program that converts a temp to Celsius or Fahrenheit, and displays the conversion to the first decimal place. My issue lies in my print lines.

As you can see in my code I have attempted to use the round() function while concatenating. Although I have attempted to convert the would be float to a str(), when I run my program, i am given the following error.

## TypeError: type str doesn't define *round* method

for the following line

## print (round(str(temp), 1)+ " degrees celsius = " + str(degF) + " degrees Fahrenheit. ")

and similarly for the print line in my elif bloc.
Any help understanding and solving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
temp=float(input("Enter a temperature value to convert: "))
unit=str(input("Convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius? Enter f or c: "))

if unit=="c" or unit == "C":
    degC=(temp)
    temp=(1.8*temp)+32
    print (round(str(temp), 1) + " degrees fahrenheit = " + str(degC) + " degrees Celsius. ")
elif unit=="f" or unit == "F":
    degF=(temp)
    temp=(temp-32)/1.8
    print (round(str(temp), 1)+ " degrees celsius = " + str(degF) + " degrees Fahrenheit. ")
else:
    print("you did not enter an f or c. Goodbye ")
```

My outputs should be rounded to the first decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert `temp` to a string. Keep it as a float for `round`. Turn the resultant after `round` into a `str` for concatenation

```
str(round(temp, 1))
```

Comment: If i leave temp as a float, i cannot concatenate with the following string statements

Answer (score 0):

Your operations are in the wrong order.  Round first, *then* convert to string:

```
print (str(round(temp), 1)+ " degrees celsius = " ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a classroom assignment to use the round function, I don't think the round function is needed.

```
print ("%.1f degrees Celsius = %.1f degrees Fahrenheit" % (temp, degC))
```